# list automatically changing without reference

Tags: python, list

I have a list of links which i am getting from `BeuitfulSoup` object, after `links2=links1`then i edited `links1` ,but `links2` got changed as well so i test in IDLE. 
Example of a list which i want to modify but keep the original one intact, how can i do it?

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=a
a.append(4)
print b
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

i want `b` to stay [1,2,3]

Comment: `b = a[:]` or `b = list(a)`

Comment: @Tomothy32 does this create a new list or just copies the reference of original one?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have reopened the question because it is no longer a duplicate of _that_ question, but it is still a duplicate as referenced by @AndrasDeak.

Comment: For additional info see a good tutorial and https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Selcuk Why not just replace the duplicate target? Reopening just so we can reclose seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: @tripleee I saw the post when it was bumped by the unhammer. My suggestion came after. I suspect if Selcuk knew about the better target they'd have edited the dupe list instead.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thanks a lot great reference, really explains a lot of what actually happens behind the scenes.